# How to filter the result of a previous regex group keeping the original group results

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Using *JavaScript Regex*, I need to based on the below string:

```
word1 w'or""d2 word3
"word4"word5
word6
```

**Have this result:**

```
word1
word2
word3
word4word5
word6
```

**I tried this:**

```
\S+/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/nsIA2Y/2

Which groups correctly the words based on spaces, however, I could not find a way to remove the " and ' characters keeping the grouped words together as in the example. Tried several ways with groupings, but my knowledge is limited.

Please explain the solution as well.

Comment: What you want as output, an array with the words or an string with new lines (`\n` character) between the words?

Comment: an array of words

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex `/[^\w\s]/` to do this. `/[^\w\s]/` will math all characters that is not word or space and then remove them with `replace()`.

Demo:

```js
var a = `word1 w'or""d2 word3`;
var b = `"word4"word5`;
var c = `word6`;

console.log(a.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '\n'));
console.log(b.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '\n'));
console.log(c.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '\n'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem might be simply solved with a string replace, and regular expression doesn't seem to be necessary, or if so, maybe this expression would simply do that.

```js
const regex = /["']+/gm;
const str = `word1 f'dfretretr""ret word2 word3

"word4"word5
word6 word7
`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/AaVvFE/1), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/AaVvFE/1debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Comment: I understand your point, but I simplified my case in the question to help others, in my scenario the regex is more complex, which is why I had to use regex.

Comment: Do you have a solution not using replace? just the regex?

Answer (score 1):

You can post process your matched array by calling a `.replace`:

```js
const str = `word1 w'or""d2 word3
"word4"word5
word6`
var arr = str.match(/\S+/g).map(s => s.replace(/['"]+/g, ''))

console.log(arr)
//=> ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4word5", "word6"]
```

`.map()` method will create a new array with the results of calling a provided function (`.replace()` in our case) on every element that we got from `.match()` function.

Comment: Note that you could also do: `str.replace(/['"]+/g, '').match(/\S+/g)` for this simple case.